# How to get a property loaded by spring in non-spring loaded java classes

Tags: spring

can someone tell me how to get a property loaded by spring porpertyconfigurer in a java class not loaded by spring? I  thought of writing a singleton class implementing

> ApplicationContextAware

and retrieve the property values.Is there any other better approach? or does Spring  have any util classes to get the loaded properties?

Answer (score 1):

The PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is a BeanFactoryPostProcessor, a specialized utility for post-processing bean definitions, and as such it is only relevant to the bean factory itself. The use case you have in mind is just not covered by it, the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer does not lend its properties to the ApplicationContext, nor does it have a getProperties() (or similar) method.

AFAIK, you will have to introduce some value-holder bean, that will hold the property value for you

Comment: Thanks Sean.I finaly end up in the value holder bean only.